# Can not view fan speed rpm in hp 4530s laptop

Tags: linux, ubuntu, fan, sensors, lm-sensors

Output of sensors is:

```
~$ sensors
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +31.0°C  (crit = +128.0°C)
temp2:         +0.0°C  (crit = +128.0°C)
temp3:        +31.0°C  (crit = +128.0°C)
temp4:        +31.0°C  (crit = +128.0°C)
temp5:        +31.0°C  (crit = +128.0°C)
temp6:         +0.0°C  (crit = +128.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Physical id 0:  +51.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +85.0°C)
Core 0:         +51.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +85.0°C)
Core 1:         +51.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +85.0°C)
```

And output of sensor detect is:

```
sudo sensors-detect 
[sudo] password for vahid: 
# sensors-detect revision 6170 (2013-05-20 21:25:22 +0200)
# System: Hewlett-Packard HP ProBook 4530s [A0001D02] (laptop)
# Board: Hewlett-Packard 167C

This program will help you determine which kernel modules you need
to load to use lm_sensors most effectively. It is generally safe
and recommended to accept the default answers to all questions,
unless you know what you're doing.

Some south bridges, CPUs or memory controllers contain embedded sensors.
Do you want to scan for them? This is totally safe. (YES/no): yes
Module cpuid loaded successfully.
Silicon Integrated Systems SIS5595...                       No
VIA VT82C686 Integrated Sensors...                          No
VIA VT8231 Integrated Sensors...                            No
AMD K8 thermal sensors...                                   No
AMD Family 10h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 11h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 12h and 14h thermal sensors...                   No
AMD Family 15h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 15h power sensors...                             No
AMD Family 16h power sensors...                             No
Intel digital thermal sensor...                             Success!
    (driver `coretemp')
Intel AMB FB-DIMM thermal sensor...                         No
VIA C7 thermal sensor...                                    No
VIA Nano thermal sensor...                                  No

Some Super I/O chips contain embedded sensors. We have to write to
standard I/O ports to probe them. This is usually safe.
Do you want to scan for Super I/O sensors? (YES/no): Yes
Probing for Super-I/O at 0x2e/0x2f
Trying family `National Semiconductor/ITE'...               No
Trying family `SMSC'...                                     Yes
Found unknown chip with ID 0x0701
Probing for Super-I/O at 0x4e/0x4f
Trying family `National Semiconductor/ITE'...               No
Trying family `SMSC'...                                     No
Trying family `VIA/Winbond/Nuvoton/Fintek'...               No
Trying family `ITE'...                                      No

Some hardware monitoring chips are accessible through the ISA I/O ports.
We have to write to arbitrary I/O ports to probe them. This is usually
safe though. Yes, you do have ISA I/O ports even if you do not have any
ISA slots! Do you want to scan the ISA I/O ports? (YES/no): Yes
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM78' at 0x290...       No
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM79' at 0x290...       No
Probing for `Winbond W83781D' at 0x290...                   No
Probing for `Winbond W83782D' at 0x290...                   No

Lastly, we can probe the I2C/SMBus adapters for connected hardware
monitoring devices. This is the most risky part, and while it works
reasonably well on most systems, it has been reported to cause trouble
on some systems.
Do you want to probe the I2C/SMBus adapters now? (YES/no): Yes
Sorry, no supported PCI bus adapters found.
Module i2c-dev loaded successfully.

Next adapter: i915 gmbus ssc (i2c-0)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): yes

Next adapter: i915 gmbus vga (i2c-1)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): yes

Next adapter: i915 gmbus panel (i2c-2)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): yes
Client found at address 0x4f
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM75'...                No
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM75A'...               No
Probing for `Dallas Semiconductor DS75'...                  No
Probing for `Maxim MAX6642'...                              No
Probing for `Texas Instruments TMP421'...                   No
Probing for `Texas Instruments TMP422'...                   No
Probing for `Maxim MAX6633/MAX6634/MAX6635'...              No
Probing for `NXP/Philips SA56004'...                        No

Next adapter: i915 gmbus dpc (i2c-3)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): yes

Next adapter: i915 gmbus dpb (i2c-4)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): yes

Next adapter: i915 gmbus dpd (i2c-5)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): yes

Next adapter: DPDDC-D (i2c-6)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): yes

Now follows a summary of the probes I have just done.
Just press ENTER to continue:  

Driver `coretemp':
  * Chip `Intel digital thermal sensor' (confidence: 9)

To load everything that is needed, add this to /etc/modules:
#----cut here----
# Chip drivers
coretemp
#----cut here----
If you have some drivers built into your kernel, the list above will
contain too many modules. Skip the appropriate ones!

Do you want to add these lines automatically to /etc/modules? (yes/NO)yes
Successful!

Monitoring programs won't work until the needed modules are
loaded. You may want to run 'service kmod start'
to load them.

Unloading i2c-dev... OK
Unloading cpuid... OK
```

So I just want to view fan speed rpm, because I can change it ([with](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2008756&page=4)) and want set it up.

Comment: there probably isn't much you can do. HP's are notorious for issues with sensors and fan controls. I was never able to resolve any of the issues I had with my fans not being aggressive enough, even/especially when contacting HP for an unlocked bios with full power management controls. Also, it looks like lm-sensors has selected the CoreTemp driver, which does not appear to have Fan capability: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/hwmon/coretemp.c

Comment: @FrankThomas Thanks. I can change fan rpm, but I can't view fan speed? In windows I can view fan speed with all softwares! Why I can't do that in Linux?